# Python weekday() for getting Sunday as 1 & Saturday as 7

Tags: python, datetime

What is the equivalent of `datetime.isoweekday()` for keeping Sunday as 1 and Saturday as 7 ?

Python's `weekday()` didn't help either. Are there alternative ways except getting clumsy by subclassing or doing weird arithmetic (addition, mod 7)?

I find it strange for not having a builtin method for a popular representation. - end of rant -

Comment: @mikeb I need to say as (dt.isoweekday()+1) %7 wherever I need to invoke. Don't you feel this gets polluted soon ?

Comment: Make a function out of it?

Comment: @itsneo: You've got the addition/mod operations in the wrong order there; if you want it from 1-7, you'd do `dt.isoweekday() % 7 + 1`.

Comment: @pfnuesel Unfortunately Python doesn't allow adding functions to built-in types. Subclassing is ugly though :p

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Interesting ! So I finally have to settle writing a static method otherwise keep using these lookups or arithmetic wherever I need the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the last value on the array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1][datetime.isoweekday(dt)]` or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1][dt.isoweekday()]` The first value is never used of course

Comment: @JohnLaRooy If you can write that as answer I wish to accept it. This is lot cleaner, we can add that list as global variable somewhere.

Comment: @itsneo: Add a function, then you don't have to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookup table like this

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1][datetime.isoweekday(dt)]
```

or

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1][dt.isoweekday()]
```

The first value in the table is never used of course

Comment: I wonder if it isn't nicer to use a list like `["NEVER USED", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]`.

Comment: or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0][dt.weekday()]` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday